# Protractor test not clicking my button/element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

my scenario looks like this:
1. open login page
2. enter username,
3. enter password,
4. click login,
5. role selection modal opens with list of possible user roles
6. click on 1st role.

My test looks like that:

```
'use strict';

describe('Login page', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get('/#/login');
  });

  it('should login', function () {

    var _user = element(by.model('loginForm.exchange.user'));
    var _pass = element(by.model('loginForm.exchange.password'));
    var loginButton = element(by.xpath('/html/body/snap-content/ui-view/div/section/content/div/div/div[2]/div/form/button'));

    _user.sendKeys('myUsername');
    _pass.sendKeys('myPassword');

    loginButton.click();

    var _roleModal = by.className('modal-dialog');
    browser.driver.wait(function () {
      return browser.driver.isElementPresent(_roleModal);
    }, 5000)
      .then(function () {
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        console.log('modal now opened.');

        var _elementInModal = by.css('[ng-click="cancel()"]');

        browser.driver.wait(function () {
          return browser.driver.isElementPresent(_elementInModal);
        }, 1000)
          .then(function () {
            browser.driver.sleep(2000);

            console.log('element present.');

            // issue here being, I can't access the roles listed in modal, even though I've created a check if the button with cancel() exists in modal itself.
            // using by.xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/form/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]') to fetch 1st role doesn't work either.

            element.all(by.repeater('role in userRoles')).then(function (role) {
              console.log('HUEY! ROLE!', role);
              var titleElement = role[0].element(by.css('media-body'));
              console.log(titleElement);
            });
          });
      });

  }, 30000);
});
```

Keep in mind when talking about modal, this is the bootstrap modal (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Modal template:

```
  <div ng-switch-when="userRoles">
    <div class="card">
        <ul class="table-view" >
          <li ng-repeat="role in userRoles" class="table-view-cell" ng-click="save(role)">
              <a class="navigate-right">
                <div class="media-body">
                  {{role.LTEXT}}
                </div>
             </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is driving me crazy for the past few days. I just can't seem to select roles from existing modal. Even if debugging from VSCode using node debugging tool, no matter which by* I chose, I can't get anything printed out.

Comment: Are there any errors?  And just FYI, if you only want the first item from that `.all` method, you can use the function [.first()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) instead of indexing it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I get the timeout error after 31ish seconds (as set up at the end line of my test)

Comment: @gregor note that you probably meant to have `.media-body` CSS selector instead of `media-body`.

Comment: What output are you getting, do you see `HUEY! ROLE!` printed?

Comment: @alecxe I'm getting no output from that part. No "HUEY! ROLE!". Last console log is "element present.". Also, changing media-body to .media-body or using by.className didn't brought nothing either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why that is but, after 10 hours I've finally found what the reason was.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

This means, I'm not waiting for any "angular" things as the protractor FAQ states:

> If you need to navigate to a page which does not use Angular, you can
>   turn off waiting for Angular by setting browser.ignoreSynchronization
>   = true

Since I still can't understand why is that so because my whole project uses Angular, why did this helped me resolve the issue?

Is it because I was trying to get data from modal, which was created by bootstrap create modal method and was called within controller? Maybe, however there's no info or similar issue out there.

So if yourself are having issues with detecting elements using modals, ignoreSynchronization is probably the first thing you should try.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any action on `titleElement` so Protractor doesn't perform the actual lookup. From the [ElementFinder documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder):

> An ElementFinder does not actually attempt to find the element until an action is called, which means they can be set up in helper files before the page is available.

Your spec times out because it doesn't have any return action (e.g. `expect()` method) and your `console.log()` statement has nothing to print out. You could do this instead:

```
expect(titleElement.getText()).toBe('INSERT_EXPECTED_TEXT');
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Seems logically, but what doesn't fit in is the console.log, which should at least be printed with empty string, object or anything else. I never get to the inner .then() element meaning, he doesn't even find the elements by repeater.